# Building Astro Component Library with Tailwind Integration

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, astrojs

I'm currently building a project which consists of a component library based on Astro, I want to use Tailwind as well to style the components and export them for use in other projects.
I followed both of the guides to build an NPM Package and to setup the Tailwind integration, but I can't seem to get the styles to actually appear on my components, any ideas/tips?

https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/publish-to-npm/#integrations-library

https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/tailwind/#configuration

Directory Structure:
[image]

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-new-component-directory",
  "description": "A new Astro component directory",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./index.ts"
  },
  "files": [
    "src",
    "index.ts"
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "astro-component"
  ],
  "scripts": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "astro": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "astro": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@astrojs/check": "^0.3.1",
    "@astrojs/tailwind": "^5.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

Astro Config

```
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import tailwind from "@astrojs/tailwind";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [tailwind()]
});
```

Tailwind Config

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{astro,html,js,jsx,md,mdx,svelte,ts,tsx,vue}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

As far as I know, that should be enough for the integration to work and the styles being available on the components, however I can apply all the classes I want and the component still shows as a basic title